# work document , Ctrl+B a single word , making other /entire document bold

Tags: ms-word, formatting

1. Clicking "Ctrl+B" on a word documents, updating other part of the document as Bold (randomly)
2. Also adding other formatting on the document such as bullets , numbering etc

Answer (score 0):

Quote

In Word 2007
Solving the problem is a bit more problematic in Word 2007 because the Modify Style dialog for the Normal style does not include the “Automatically update” check box. Consequently, if the Normal style acquires the “Automatically update” property, it can be reversed only with a macro, as follows:

Press Alt+F11 to display the Visual Basic Editor. Press Ctrl+G to show the Immediate Window.

Type:

ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).AutomaticallyUpdate = False

Press Enter, and save the document.

If the issue arises with a style other than Normal, it can be dealt with in the same manner as in previous versions. In the Styles group on the Home tab, click the dialog launcher (arrow in the bottom right corner) to open the Styles pane. Select the misbehaving style, click on the arrow to open the menu, choose Modify, and proceed as instructed above for other versions.